# Jupyter Notebook Looking for Python 2.7 after Python Install

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

So this happened immediately after i ran:

**brew install python2**

on an environment where I already had jupyter running fine in a python3 environment. I figure that the python2 install has messed up stuff, because I now get the following error when I run "jupyter notebook":

**-bash: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

I have tried brew uninstalling both python and python2, then reinstalling. I also pip-autoremoved jupyter before doing that. None of the above have worked.

I think the principal problem is that I'm not uninstalling jupyter correctly. Even when I pip uninstall jupyter *and* pip-autoremove jupyter -y, my terminal is still finding a jupyter command in my usr/local/bin

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you run `brew doctor`?

Comment: Did u check if those files exist?

Comment: I tried installing python2.7 to have those files exist and it still didn't work then. The real goal is just to go back to my previous installation with Python3. 

I also ran brew doctor and it says everything is ready to brew.